# Update of root certificates on docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, certificate

If I understand correctly, on standard Ubuntu systems for example, root certificates are provided by ca-certificates package and get updated when the package itself is updated.

But how can the root certificates be updated when using docker containers ? Is there a common preferred way of doing this, or must the containers be redeployed with an up-to-date docker image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containers must be redeployed with an up-to-date image.

The Docker Hub base images like [ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) actually get updated fairly regularly, and if you look at the [tag list](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags) you can see that there are several date-stamped variants of the images.  So one approach that will get you pretty close to current is to always (have your CI system) pull the base image before you build.

```
docker pull ubuntu:18.04
docker build .
```

If you can't do that, or if you're working from some sort of derived image that updates less frequently, you can just manually run `apt-get upgrade` in your Dockerfile.  Doing this in the same place you're otherwise installing packages makes sense.  It needs to be in the same `RUN` line as a matching `apt-get update`, and you might need some way to force Docker to not cache that update line to get current updates.

```sh
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Have an option to force rebuilds; the RUN line won't be
# cacheable if the dependency_stamp option changes
ARG dependency_stamp
ENV dependency_stamp=${dependency_stamp:-unknown}
RUN touch /dependencies.${dependency_stamp}

# Update base OS packages and install other things we need
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install \
      --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      ...
```

If you find yourself doing this routinely, maintaining your own base images that are upgraded to current packages but don't have anything else installed can be helpful; if you find yourself doing *that*, you might have more control over the process and get smaller images if you build an image `FROM ubuntu` and install *e.g.* Python, rather than building an image `FROM python` and then installing updates over it.

Comment: What about embedded docker in remote site (without orchestrator and remote access). There is no common way to keep the certificate up-to-date without human intervention (like deploy new version of the docker) ?

Comment: How would you deploy ordinary software updates into that environment?  This is no different.

Comment: Fair point. So your advice is to rebuild your docker periodically with updated version of the internal package, and not perform some kind of auto-update feature (like call update-ca each week)